# How do you find which script is causing the CSP error?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, security, content-security-policy

Google started throwing this message out of the blue:

```
"Content Security Policy of your site blocks the use of 'eval' in JavaScript"
```

I had no policy config'd, so to test, I tried setting my CSP to (both in the HTML and in the web.config):

```
<add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; 
    script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://js.squareup.com/; report-uri /csp_report_parser;" />
```

I get nothing in the report and google won't tell me the source:

[image: csp error]

How do I find the offending code?

Thanks!

Comment: Try https://validator.w3.org/unicorn/ maye will tell you something useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add 'report-sample' token to the script-src directive. It should send samples of code caused the violation - 40 chars, also line number will be send (as I can see you do use violation reports feature).
2. In the browser console you could see the function names (green arrow) and line number (blue arrow at the printscreen below) where the violation occurred.
   The results of `report-sample` underlined in red:
   [image: printscreen]
3. You can catch [SecurityPolicyViolation event](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#securitypolicyviolationevent) by javascript - all what going to be sent in the violation report is accessible, include line/column number.

> Google started throwing this message out of the blue:

It could not be out of blue. May be the default CSP rules was activated after software upgrade or you touch the settings.

Anyway you CSP `script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'` allows eval-expressions, so you have somewhere another CSP issued.

Comment: Yeah, that last line is what had me puzzled.  I didn't have one configured at all before this. I'm thinking my host implemented one.  Thank you for this detailed explanation!

Comment: The `original-policy` field in the violation report should contain actual CSP that been breached. Also you can use developers tool (browser console) to see the CPS HTTP-header delivered from the server. The CSP could be delivered with meta-tag, but in this case it does not send reports. As you have got reports - it's not your variant. And to publish 2 CSP header at the same time - is not an ordinary thing, because at the server side the last issued header overrides all previous with the same name. Just pull the thread to unravel the whole ball.